# Do I still have to include data owner in privacy policy if I do not collect any data?

Tags: privacy

I have an iPhone app and need to write a privacy policy for it (Apple requires it for this type of apps).

I know that privacy policy should include data owner's contact information (name, address), it is required in some countries. Is it still required if I collect no data at all? My privacy policy could be very short:

> We do not collect any kind of data from you. Apple Inc might collect some data and provide it to us as stated in your device's Pivacy Policy.

Do I still have to add my contact info to that?

Answer (score 1):

I'd be interested in hearing what kind of app it is. Since you're saying that *Apple requires* already suggests that you do in fact have some connection with user data in some way ([I've written a blog post outlining this process](http://www.iubenda.com/blog/privacy-policy-for-ios-apps/)).

When I last checked these were the categories:

> (i) Apps that collect user data must have a privacy policy and secure
>   user consent for the collection. This includes—but isn’t limited
>   to—apps that implement HealthKit or other health/medical technologies,
>   HomeKit, Keyboard extensions, Apple Pay, include a login, or access
>   user data from the device (e.g. location, contacts, calendar, etc.).

- (from 5.1.1 in the App Store Review Guidelines)

> Moreover, apps in the Kids Category or those that collect, transmit,
>   or have the capability to share personal information (e.g. name,
>   address, email, location, photos, videos, drawings, the ability to
>   chat, other personal data, or persistent identifiers used in
>   combination with any of the above) from a minor must include a privacy
>   policy and must comply with all applicable children's privacy
>   statutes. For the sake of clarity, the parental gate requirement for
>   the Kid’s Category is generally not the same as securing parental
>   consent to collect personal data under these privacy statutes.

- (from 5.1.4)

All of these categories suggest some sort of user data processing.

Regarding the Owner field: yes you're right many countries require basic address and email options there. The easiest way of course to evade putting down your home address is to have some sort of work address available, or non-compliance in that particular element (which of course I can't suggest).